# RewriteRule with question marks with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
<Files *.php>
XSendFile On
SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1
</Files>
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteBase /

# forward app requests
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) plugins/webdav/site/control/$1 [QSA,L]

# route everything via index.php if it doesn't exist as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_page_url=$1 [QSA]
```

what i am trying to do is to add ?v= in the url
example
mysite.com/?v=filename

i have tried this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^v=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$      index.php?_page_url=$1     [NC,L]
```

Comment: @mikerockett can you help please

Comment: Do you want both parameters `_page_url=` and `v=` in `index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your backreference is incorrect. To backreference a matching pattern from the `RewriteCond`, you need to use the `%` sign. `$` is to backreference the `RewriteRule` matching patterns

So your rules should read like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^v=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$      index.php?_page_url=%1     [NC,L]
```

HTH